# Pandas: Handling offset timezone value when using 'DatetimeIndex'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `datetime` column `EST`

```
EST
2017-01-01 19:00:00-05:00
2017-01-01 19:01:00-05:00
2017-01-01 19:02:00-05:00
2017-01-01 19:03:00-05:00
2017-01-01 19:05:00-05:00
2017-01-01 19:06:00-05:00
....
2017-12-31 23:01:00-05:00
```

Here you can see that there is trailing `-05:00` on every time. This trailing `-05:00` was added when I converted from `GMT` to `EST`.

How do I remove `-05:00`?

The reason is because when I do:

`df['EST'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['EST']')`

I get this error:

`TypeError: [datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 31, 19, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))`

Could you please help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the `-05:00` by using [`Series.dt.tz_localize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) and set it to `None`. Then we can use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['EST'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EST']).dt.tz_localize(None)
```

```
                    EST
0   2017-01-01 19:00:00
1   2017-01-01 19:01:00
2   2017-01-01 19:02:00
3   2017-01-01 19:03:00
4   2017-01-01 19:05:00
5   2017-01-01 19:06:00
6   2017-12-31 23:01:00
```

If `EST` is your index, use:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['EST']).dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Comment: This works but is this optimal solution in such cases?

Comment: what is the difference between `pd.DatetimeIndex(df['EST']')` and `pd.to_datetime(df['EST'])`? since I have been using `pd.DatetimeIndex`

Comment: I assume that 'EST' is a column in this case and not your index. If it is your index, you are correct we have to use `pd.DatetimeIndex`, see my edit. @floss

Comment: I used `pd.to_datetime(df['EST']).dt.tz_localize(None)` and I got this error: `ValueError: Array must be all same time zone`  ( and )   `ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True`

Comment: Not sure, have to see more data to help here. Maybe try `pd.to_datetime(df['EST'], utc=True).dt.tz_localize(None)`, although I doubt this will help the problem. @floss

Comment: Since we are doing `utc=True`, it may not work because our datatime is in `EST` and not `UTC`

Comment: The offset starts with `-05:00` but with `Daylights Saving` it goes to `-04:00` and when it ends it comes back to `-05:00`. Is this what is causing the error?

Comment: Not sure, if I was you I would delete this question and submit a new one where you describe your problem better and capture the edge cases as well, so if people use your data to reproduce an answer, they will have the same errors. @floss

Comment: Can you please confirm that `df['EST'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[EST'].str.rsplit('-', 1).str[0])` would give same result as your descrived above?

Comment: I can confirm that for the example dataset your provided. If that generalizes to your whole dataset, then it works correctly. @floss

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use `.dt.tz_localize` with option `None` assume your `EST` column is already `datetime` dtype

Sample data:

```
df['EST']:
0   2017-01-01 19:00:00-05:00
1   2017-01-01 19:01:00-05:00
2   2017-01-01 19:02:00-05:00
3   2017-01-01 19:03:00-05:00
4   2017-01-01 19:05:00-05:00
5   2017-01-01 19:06:00-05:00
Name: EST, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
```

Output with `.dt.tz_localize`

```
df['EST'].dt.tz_localize(None)

Out[2386]:
0   2017-01-01 19:00:00
1   2017-01-01 19:01:00
2   2017-01-01 19:02:00
3   2017-01-01 19:03:00
4   2017-01-01 19:05:00
5   2017-01-01 19:06:00
Name: EST, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: When I do `df['EST'].dt.tz_localize(None)`, I get this error `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: @floss: it means your df['EST'] is not `datetime` dtype. You need convert it to datetime using `pd.to_datetime` or construct direct datetimeindex using `pd.DatetimeIndex` and specify `tz` info. However, the final output will reflect the `-05:00` into the time. It means it will be `00:00:xx` and date increases 1 day

Comment: my `df['EST']` is in the proper format but when I converted from `GMT` to `EST`, I got the trailing offset value `-05:00`.